# Can we have a private constructor in a static class?

Tags: c#

I have a doubt that a static class can contain a private constructor.

Comment: If you have Visual Studio (or similar) installed, my guess is that it'd take you less than 1 minute to compile and check this for yourself...

Comment: Johann, that is no reason not to ask it on SO. See the FAQ.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Static classes cannot have instance constructors

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/79b3xss3.aspx

The following list provides the main features of a static class:

> - Contains only static members.
> - Cannot be instantiated.
> - Is sealed.
> - Cannot contain Instance Constructors.

Answer (score 6):

A static class cannot have **any** instance constructor ( see [CS0710](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/78z8kh57%28VS.80%29.aspx) ), whether it be public, private, protected or internal.

See the following article for more info.

[Static Classes and Static Class Members (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/79b3xss3%28VS.80%29.aspx)

Comment: @jonathan: I'm looking at a `public static class` in Reflector an ildasm, but can only find the `private static void .cctor()` static constructor. Where would this private instance constructor be?

Answer (score 5):

What would this constructor do? The class is static, so it is never instantiated. You can have a static constructor on a non-static class to initialize static fields, but on a static class, the only constructor that makes sense is the static constructor, and that gets called be the CLR.

*Addition*: [Jon Skeet posted an article](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/01/26/type-initialization-changes-in-net-4-0.aspx) about the timing of the initialization of the static class (normally it's initialized on first use, but sometimes you want to initialize it when the program starts) and a *possible* change in .net 4.

Comment: @Jonathan Wow, that's weird. I'm trying to think how that would ever have been useful, but as they replaced that I think they had the same conclusion :)

Comment: @Jonathan tell the CLR that a _static_ class can't be instantiated for Real?

Answer (score 4):

Your doubt is correct.

A static class can only have a static constructor and public/private does not apply since your code can never call this constructor (the CLR does).

So you may not use a access modifier (public/private/...) on a static constructor.

Answer (score 3):

rule is static classes cannot have instance constructors